# Percentage and income distribution (arithmatic)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A person gives 30% of his income to his elder daughter and 40% of
>   remaining to his younger daughter. And he distributes rest of the money
>   equally among his 3 sons. If each son got Rs. 672, then how much money
>   did the elder and younger daughter got?

$$\frac{6}{10}\frac{7}{10}x=2016$$

$$x=4800$$

Required amount=

$$\frac{30}{100}4800+\frac{7}{10}\frac{4}{10}*4800$$

=2784

However, the answer given is:

1344

Comment: $1344$ is the amount that the younger daughter got ($28\%$) while the elder daughter got $1440$ ($30\%$) and each son $672$ ($14\%$)

Comment: Your answer for the total amount, what you call the required amount, is correct. Just use the first number in the sum for the elder daughter and the second number for the younger daughter.

Answer (score 1):

Consider only percentages of the whole amount.

Elder daughter gets $30 \%$

Remainder is $70 \%$

$40 \%$ of that is $(0.4)(70) = 28 \%$ of the whole, and that's what the younger daughter gets

Total disbursed so far = $58 \%$.

Remainder = $42 \%$, so each son gets $14 \%$

$14 \%$ of the whole is Rs. $672$, which makes the whole Rs. $672(\frac{100}{14}) = 4800$.

The relevant amounts are therefore $30 \%$ of $4800$ = Rs. $1440$ (elder daughter) and $28 \%$ of $4800$ = Rs. $1344$.